# Car not showing in Grove Street garage

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just purchased an Adder on my phone and went to my Grove Street garage to find my other 3 cars, but not the Adder.

I had the money, so I tried purchasing another except it told me my garage was full. I left the area, came back and it's still not in there.

I can't store any more than the 3 cars I have in there and it's quite frustrating since it's the only garage I can get.

Comment: Sometimes it can take a few minutes for a purchased car to show up.  It's not ready until you get a text back from the dealership.

Comment: Well I did get the text and then went and checked repeatedly and it wasn't there any of the times, but oddly I just checked again(about 20 min later) and now it's in there... strange... but thank you any way!

Comment: @CaulynDarr Be sure to put that as a full answer!

Answer (score 2):

Purchased cars can take some time to show up, often a few minutes.

An indicator that it is on its way is receiving a text from the dealership.